# How to get the Lat, Long of a clicked location using leaflet Api

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am using OSM with leaflet API. Now I want to get the lat and long of a clicked location. I meant something similar to this:

> http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html

```
map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
            var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                alert("Lat, Lon : "+position.lon.toFixed(3),position.lat.toFixed(3));

        });
```

This code in open layers helps to get the lat,long values - looking for something similar using leaflet.

Any help would be really great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.latlng);
});
```

[Docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#mouseevent-latlng)

Comment: Just remember about `e: L.MouseEvent` if You use TypeScript.