# leaflet how to get latlng into html variable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I can't figure out how to extract a mouse click into latlng and then into a html variable. Here' what I've done (from post [How to get the Lat, Long of a clicked location using leaflet Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175101/how-to-get-the-lat-long-of-a-clicked-location-using-leaflet-api)):

```
var lat = map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.latlng[0]); });
```

In short, I can't figure out how to use leaflet to write to a variable. On then use that variable in html:

```
<div> <script type="text/javascript"> document.write('<"'+lat+'">')</script></div>
```

html stuff works, but not the leaflet things.
Thanks,
Dawg

Comment: I believe you've got some concepts wrong. There's no such thing as an html variable, just Javascript ones. Anyway, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Write the clicked upon coordinates onto the webpage?

Answer (score 4):

you should use `console.log(e);` to check your reference is valid.

try

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
}
```

or in your case

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latlng.lat;
}
```